# Using Spring Batch with clustered environment

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have posted two questions ([Clone table from database to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518113/clone-table-from-database-to-database), [How should I use .tasklet() / .chunk() to finish job succesfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647018/how-should-i-use-tasklet-chunk-to-finish-job-succesfully)) with working solution implemented using Spring Batch.

Now the next problem - we use Weblogic with adjusted several-nodes cluster. So, how to use batch job in this case? I saw meta-data schema in documentation - should I implement some things besides these tables? Maybe I can use adjusted Quartz jobs for this purpose?

Comment: I don't understand your questions/problems. Can you try to explain it a little bit deeper? What should your batch do (still the copy batch?)? What is the role of the cluster concerning the batch? (should it run on several nodes, does it read/write from/to several nodes)?

Comment: What should my batch do - look the second link, it's descibed into configuration and works. About role of cluster, than you start job if smth wrong with current node - the second node will handle this situation taking job from persistent repository. It seems I need to use Quartz scheduler, besides I used it earlier in project to start job manually in Spring Integration flow.